# Work with ctrl-c and ctrl-v to copy and paste into a wx.Grid in wxPython

Tags: python, wxpython, copy-paste

I am working on an program with a number of input tables for which I am using wxPython wx.Grid (primarily for Windows). I noticed that ctrl-c and ctrl-v to copy and paste doe snot simply work and I searched for solutions to prevent having to type in all numbers in the tables by hand. I found an old post by Ruben Charles here:
http://comments.gmane.org/gmane.comp.python.wxpython/26387

That seems to do more or less what I wanted, so I started working with that and made some, what I hope are improvements. (I added functionality to 'undo' with ctrl-Z, for working with single cells and for pasting if the last row or column falls outside of the grid table.)

Are there better ways to do this, or might you have advice for improvement?
Particularly: How to make this work with Python 3.5?

```
import wx
import wx.grid

class MyFrame(wx.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent, ID, title, pos=wx.DefaultPosition, size=wx.Size(800, 400), style=wx.DEFAULT_FRAME_STYLE):
        wx.Frame.__init__(self, parent, ID, title, pos, size, style)
        agrid = MyGrid(self, -1, wx.WANTS_CHARS)
        agrid.CreateGrid(7, 7)
        for count in range(3):
            for count2 in range(3):
                agrid.SetCellValue(count, count2, str(count + count2))

class MyGrid(wx.grid.Grid):
    """ A Copy&Paste enabled grid class"""
    def __init__(self, parent, id, style):
        wx.grid.Grid.__init__(self, parent, id, wx.DefaultPosition, wx.DefaultSize, style)
        wx.EVT_KEY_DOWN(self, self.OnKey)
        self.data4undo = [0, 0, '']

    def OnKey(self, event):
        # If Ctrl+C is pressed...
        if event.ControlDown() and event.GetKeyCode() == 67:
            self.copy()
        # If Ctrl+V is pressed...
        if event.ControlDown() and event.GetKeyCode() == 86:
            self.paste('clip')
        # If Ctrl+Z is pressed...
        if event.ControlDown() and event.GetKeyCode() == 90:
            if self.data4undo[2] != '':
                self.paste('undo')
        # If del is pressed...
        if event.GetKeyCode() == 127:
            # Call delete method
            self.delete()
        # Skip other Key events
        if event.GetKeyCode():
            event.Skip()
            return

    def copy(self):
        # Number of rows and cols
        print self.GetSelectionBlockBottomRight()
        print self.GetGridCursorRow()
        print self.GetGridCursorCol()
        if self.GetSelectionBlockTopLeft() == []:
            rows = 1
            cols = 1
            iscell = True
        else:
            rows = self.GetSelectionBlockBottomRight()[0][0] - self.GetSelectionBlockTopLeft()[0][0] + 1
            cols = self.GetSelectionBlockBottomRight()[0][1] - self.GetSelectionBlockTopLeft()[0][1] + 1
            iscell = False
        # data variable contain text that must be set in the clipboard
        data = ''
        # For each cell in selected range append the cell value in the data variable
        # Tabs '\t' for cols and '\r' for rows
        for r in range(rows):
            for c in range(cols):
                if iscell:
                    data += str(self.GetCellValue(self.GetGridCursorRow() + r, self.GetGridCursorCol() + c))
                else:
                    data += str(self.GetCellValue(self.GetSelectionBlockTopLeft()[0][0] + r, self.GetSelectionBlockTopLeft()[0][1] + c))
                if c < cols - 1:
                    data += '\t'
            data += '\n'
        # Create text data object
        clipboard = wx.TextDataObject()
        # Set data object value
        clipboard.SetText(data)
        # Put the data in the clipboard
        if wx.TheClipboard.Open():
            wx.TheClipboard.SetData(clipboard)
            wx.TheClipboard.Close()
        else:
            wx.MessageBox("Can't open the clipboard", "Error")

    def paste(self, stage):
        if stage == 'clip':
            clipboard = wx.TextDataObject()
            if wx.TheClipboard.Open():
                wx.TheClipboard.GetData(clipboard)
                wx.TheClipboard.Close()
            else:
                wx.MessageBox("Can't open the clipboard", "Error")
            data = clipboard.GetText()
            if self.GetSelectionBlockTopLeft() == []:
                rowstart = self.GetGridCursorRow()
                colstart = self.GetGridCursorCol()
            else:
                rowstart = self.GetSelectionBlockTopLeft()[0][0]
                colstart = self.GetSelectionBlockTopLeft()[0][1]
        elif stage == 'undo':
            data = self.data4undo[2]
            rowstart = self.data4undo[0]
            colstart = self.data4undo[1]
        else:
            wx.MessageBox("Paste method "+stage+" does not exist", "Error")
        text4undo = ''
        # Convert text in a array of lines
        for y, r in enumerate(data.splitlines()):
            # Convert c in a array of text separated by tab
            for x, c in enumerate(r.split('\t')):
                if y + rowstart < self.NumberRows and x + colstart < self.NumberCols :
                    text4undo += str(self.GetCellValue(rowstart + y, colstart + x)) + '\t'
                    self.SetCellValue(rowstart + y, colstart + x, c)
            text4undo = text4undo[:-1] + '\n'
        if stage == 'clip':
            self.data4undo = [rowstart, colstart, text4undo]
        else:
            self.data4undo = [0, 0, '']

    def delete(self):
        # print "Delete method"
        # Number of rows and cols
        if self.GetSelectionBlockTopLeft() == []:
            rows = 1
            cols = 1
        else:
            rows = self.GetSelectionBlockBottomRight()[0][0] - self.GetSelectionBlockTopLeft()[0][0] + 1
            cols = self.GetSelectionBlockBottomRight()[0][1] - self.GetSelectionBlockTopLeft()[0][1] + 1
        # Clear cells contents
        for r in range(rows):
            for c in range(cols):
                if self.GetSelectionBlockTopLeft() == []:
                    self.SetCellValue(self.GetGridCursorRow() + r, self.GetGridCursorCol() + c, '')
                else:
                    self.SetCellValue(self.GetSelectionBlockTopLeft()[0][0] + r, self.GetSelectionBlockTopLeft()[0][1] + c, '')

class MyApp(wx.App):
    def OnInit(self):
        frame = MyFrame(None, -1, "Copy and paste enabled only for a single range")
        frame.Show(True)
        self.SetTopWindow(frame)
        return True
def main():
    app = MyApp()
    app.MainLoop()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: Perfect for my purposes. The only thing I did was modify the multi-`if` statement in `OnKey` into a dictionary that calls the other functions and split out the paste and undo into separate cases under my `paste` definition.

Comment: Thanks for the tip Kyrubas! I never thought of using a dictionary that way.

Comment: Thanks @ROB! This is very cool and useful. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I adapted the code for class MyGrid to work with Python 2 and 3, see below.

```
class MyGrid(wx.grid.Grid):
    """ A Copy&Paste enabled grid class"""
    def __init__(self, parent, id, style):
        wx.grid.Grid.__init__(self, parent, id, wx.DefaultPosition, wx.DefaultSize, style)
        # wx.EVT_KEY_DOWN(self, self.OnKey)
        self.Bind(wx.EVT_KEY_DOWN, self.OnKey)
        self.data4undo = [0, 0, '']

    def OnKey(self, event):
        # If Ctrl+C is pressed...
        if event.ControlDown() and event.GetKeyCode() == 67:
            self.copy()
        # If Ctrl+V is pressed...
        if event.ControlDown() and event.GetKeyCode() == 86:
            self.paste('clip')
        # If Ctrl+Z is pressed...
        if event.ControlDown() and event.GetKeyCode() == 90:
            if self.data4undo[2] != '':
                self.paste('undo')
        # If del is pressed...
        if event.GetKeyCode() == 127:
            # Call delete method
            self.delete()
        # Skip other Key events
        if event.GetKeyCode():
            event.Skip()
            return

    def copy(self):
        # Number of rows and cols
        topleft = self.GetSelectionBlockTopLeft()
        if list(topleft) == []:
            topleft = []
        else:
            topleft = list(topleft[0])
        bottomright = self.GetSelectionBlockBottomRight()
        if list(bottomright) == []:
            bottomright = []
        else:
            bottomright = list(bottomright[0])
        if list(self.GetSelectionBlockTopLeft()) == []:
            rows = 1
            cols = 1
            iscell = True
        else:
            rows = bottomright[0] - topleft[0] + 1
            cols = bottomright[1] - topleft[1] + 1
            iscell = False
        # data variable contain text that must be set in the clipboard
        data = ''
        # For each cell in selected range append the cell value in the data variable
        # Tabs '    ' for cols and '\r' for rows
        for r in range(rows):
            for c in range(cols):
                if iscell:
                    data += str(self.GetCellValue(self.GetGridCursorRow() + r, self.GetGridCursorCol() + c))
                else:
                    data += str(self.GetCellValue(topleft[0] + r, topleft[1] + c))
                if c < cols - 1:
                    data += '    '
            data += '\n'
        # Create text data object
        clipboard = wx.TextDataObject()
        # Set data object value
        clipboard.SetText(data)
        # Put the data in the clipboard
        if wx.TheClipboard.Open():
            wx.TheClipboard.SetData(clipboard)
            wx.TheClipboard.Close()
        else:
            wx.MessageBox("Can't open the clipboard", "Error")

    def paste(self, stage):
        topleft = list(self.GetSelectionBlockTopLeft())
        if stage == 'clip':
            clipboard = wx.TextDataObject()
            if wx.TheClipboard.Open():
                wx.TheClipboard.GetData(clipboard)
                wx.TheClipboard.Close()
            else:
                wx.MessageBox("Can't open the clipboard", "Error")
            data = clipboard.GetText()
            if topleft == []:
                rowstart = self.GetGridCursorRow()
                colstart = self.GetGridCursorCol()
            else:
                rowstart = topleft[0][0]
                colstart = topleft[0][1]
        elif stage == 'undo':
            data = self.data4undo[2]
            rowstart = self.data4undo[0]
            colstart = self.data4undo[1]
        else:
            wx.MessageBox("Paste method "+stage+" does not exist", "Error")
        text4undo = ''
        # Convert text in a array of lines
        for y, r in enumerate(data.splitlines()):
            # Convert c in a array of text separated by tab
            for x, c in enumerate(r.split('    ')):
                if y + rowstart < self.NumberRows and x + colstart < self.NumberCols :
                    text4undo += str(self.GetCellValue(rowstart + y, colstart + x)) + '    '
                    self.SetCellValue(rowstart + y, colstart + x, c)
            text4undo = text4undo[:-1] + '\n'
        if stage == 'clip':
            self.data4undo = [rowstart, colstart, text4undo]
        else:
            self.data4undo = [0, 0, '']

    def delete(self):
        # print "Delete method"
        # Number of rows and cols
        topleft = list(self.GetSelectionBlockTopLeft())
        bottomright = list(self.GetSelectionBlockBottomRight())
        if topleft == []:
            rows = 1
            cols = 1
        else:
            rows = bottomright[0][0] - topleft[0][0] + 1
            cols = bottomright[0][1] - topleft[0][1] + 1
        # Clear cells contents
        for r in range(rows):
            for c in range(cols):
                if topleft == []:
                    self.SetCellValue(self.GetGridCursorRow() + r, self.GetGridCursorCol() + c, '')
                else:
                    self.SetCellValue(topleft[0][0] + r, topleft[0][1] + c, '')
```

Comment: Great thanks @ROB ! Full tested and working code: https://web.archive.org/web/20230401154008/https://pastebin.com/Q3BD1BWw
Note: The paste function pastes multiple columns into one column on the wx Grid (instead of same as source into multiple columns). Any Fix? Thanks.

Comment: @Lod Sorry for the delay, I only just saw your comment from Apr 1.
I think the problem is that the code you copied has a tab in the line "for x, c in enumerate(r.split('    ')):" changed into a number of spaces. It should work when you replace '    ' with '\t'.

Comment: thanks @ROB! No problem for the delay. I was away too for a while. I'll test asap. Be well!

Comment: Great @Lod! 
BTW: I just programmed something similar in Pyside6 (i.e. Qt instead of Wx) and when I compare the two now, the Qt  version seems a lot simpler. It made me wonder why I chose Wx years ago… 
I’ll try to post that version soon.

Comment: Interesting. Thanks for the suggestion @ROB! Qt looks good. I got personally into Wx for the extensive demo samples https://github.com/wxWidgets/Phoenix/tree/master/demo ,  https://github.com/wxWidgets/wxPython-Classic/tree/master/demo , but will look at Qt asap as it does seems simpler and faster development environement. Thanks again! Cheers

Comment: @Lod I put my Pyside6 code here: https://stackoverflow.com/q/76708563/4237285

Comment: Thanks @ROB for the Qt share will take a look asap. I had a new use case with your wx sample today. Basically using a button to call the copy function, but the problem was the grid was only selecting the 1st cell. I made this slight modification so it selects all the grid (mine is 15x5): `if list(self.mygrid.GetSelectionBlockTopLeft()) == []:
rows = 15 cols = 5`. With summary script here (lines 38-39 of interest): https://web.archive.org/web/20230730181223/https://pastecode.io/s/za8vvwp9 . Thanks again. Be well!

Answer (score 6):

I improved the code and added a few things like unlimited undo, deleting colums, rows, mouse right click popup etc. Tested in Python 2 & 3

```
import wx.grid
import wx


class MyGrid(wx.grid.Grid):
    def __init__(self, parent):
        wx.grid.Grid.__init__(self, parent, wx.ID_ANY, wx.DefaultPosition, wx.DefaultSize, 0)
        self.Bind(wx.EVT_KEY_DOWN, self.on_key)
        self.Bind(wx.grid.EVT_GRID_CELL_CHANGING, self.on_change)
        self.Bind(wx.grid.EVT_GRID_LABEL_RIGHT_CLICK, self.on_label_right_click)
        self.Bind(wx.grid.EVT_GRID_CELL_RIGHT_CLICK, self.on_cell_right_click)
        self.selected_rows = []
        self.selected_cols = []
        self.history = []

    def get_col_headers(self):
        return [self.GetColLabelValue(col) for col in range(self.GetNumberCols())]

    def get_table(self):
        for row in range(self.GetNumberRows()):
            result = {}
            for col, header in enumerate(self.get_col_headers()):
                result[header] = self.GetCellValue(row, col)
            yield result

    def add_rows(self, event):
        for row in self.selected_rows:
            self.InsertRows(row)
        self.add_history({"type": "add_rows", "rows": self.selected_rows})

    def delete_rows(self, event):
        self.cut(event)
        rows = []
        for row in reversed(self.selected_rows):
            rows.append((
                row,
                {  # More attributes can be added
                    "label": self.GetRowLabelValue(row),
                    "size": self.GetRowSize(row)
                }
            ))
            self.DeleteRows(row)
        self.add_history({"type": "delete_rows", "rows": rows})

    def add_cols(self, event):
        for col in self.selected_cols:
            self.InsertCols(col)
        self.add_history({"type": "add_cols", "cols": self.selected_cols})

    def delete_cols(self, event):
        self.delete(event)
        cols = []
        for col in reversed(self.selected_cols):
            cols.append((
                col,
                {  # More attributes can be added
                    "label": self.GetColLabelValue(col),
                    "size": self.GetColSize(col)
                }
            ))
            self.DeleteCols(col)
        self.add_history({"type": "delete_cols", "cols": cols})

    def on_cell_right_click(self, event):
        menus = [(wx.NewId(), "Cut", self.cut),
                 (wx.NewId(), "Copy", self.copy),
                 (wx.NewId(), "Paste", self.paste)]
        popup_menu = wx.Menu()
        for menu in menus:
            if menu is None:
                popup_menu.AppendSeparator()
                continue
            popup_menu.Append(menu[0], menu[1])
            self.Bind(wx.EVT_MENU, menu[2], id=menu[0])

        self.PopupMenu(popup_menu, event.GetPosition())
        popup_menu.Destroy()
        return

    def on_label_right_click(self, event):
        menus = [(wx.NewId(), "Cut", self.cut),
                 (wx.NewId(), "Copy", self.copy),
                 (wx.NewId(), "Paste", self.paste),
                 None]

        # Select if right clicked row or column is not in selection
        if event.GetRow() > -1:
            if not self.IsInSelection(row=event.GetRow(), col=1):
                self.SelectRow(event.GetRow())
            self.selected_rows = self.GetSelectedRows()
            menus += [(wx.NewId(), "Add row", self.add_rows)]
            menus += [(wx.NewId(), "Delete row", self.delete_rows)]
        elif event.GetCol() > -1:
            if not self.IsInSelection(row=1, col=event.GetCol()):
                self.SelectCol(event.GetCol())
            self.selected_cols = self.GetSelectedCols()
            menus += [(wx.NewId(), "Add column", self.add_cols)]
            menus += [(wx.NewId(), "Delete column", self.delete_cols)]
        else:
            return

        popup_menu = wx.Menu()
        for menu in menus:
            if menu is None:
                popup_menu.AppendSeparator()
                continue
            popup_menu.Append(menu[0], menu[1])
            self.Bind(wx.EVT_MENU, menu[2], id=menu[0])

        self.PopupMenu(popup_menu, event.GetPosition())
        popup_menu.Destroy()
        return

    def on_change(self, event):
        cell = event.GetEventObject()
        row = cell.GetGridCursorRow()
        col = cell.GetGridCursorCol()
        attribute = {"value": self.GetCellValue(row, col)}
        self.add_history({"type": "change", "cells": [(row, col, attribute)]})

    def add_history(self, change):
        self.history.append(change)

    def undo(self):
        if not len(self.history):
            return

        action = self.history.pop()
        if action["type"] == "change" or action["type"] == "delete":
            for row, col, attribute in action["cells"]:
                self.SetCellValue(row, col, attribute["value"])
                if action["type"] == "delete":
                    self.SetCellAlignment(row, col, *attribute["alignment"])  # *attribute["alignment"] > horiz, vert

        elif action["type"] == "delete_rows":
            for row, attribute in reversed(action["rows"]):
                self.InsertRows(row)
                self.SetRowLabelValue(row, attribute["label"])
                self.SetRowSize(row, attribute["size"])

        elif action["type"] == "delete_cols":
            for col, attribute in reversed(action["cols"]):
                self.InsertCols(col)
                self.SetColLabelValue(col, attribute["label"])
                self.SetColSize(col, attribute["size"])

        elif action["type"] == "add_rows":
            for row in reversed(action["rows"]):
                self.DeleteRows(row)

        elif action["type"] == "add_cols":
            for col in reversed(action["cols"]):
                self.DeleteCols(col)
        else:
            return

    def on_key(self, event):
        """
        Handles all key events.
        """
        # print(event.GetKeyCode())
        # Ctrl+C or Ctrl+Insert
        if event.ControlDown() and event.GetKeyCode() in [67, 322]:
            self.copy(event)

        # Ctrl+V
        elif event.ControlDown() and event.GetKeyCode() == 86:
            self.paste(event)

        # DEL
        elif event.GetKeyCode() == 127:
            self.delete(event)

        # Ctrl+A
        elif event.ControlDown() and event.GetKeyCode() == 65:
            self.SelectAll()

        # Ctrl+Z
        elif event.ControlDown() and event.GetKeyCode() == 90:
            self.undo()

        # Ctrl+X
        elif event.ControlDown() and event.GetKeyCode() == 88:
            # Call delete method
            self.cut(event)

        # Ctrl+V or Shift + Insert
        elif (event.ControlDown() and event.GetKeyCode() == 67) \
                or (event.ShiftDown() and event.GetKeyCode() == 322):
            self.paste(event)

        else:
            event.Skip()

    def get_selection(self):
        """
        Returns selected range's start_row, start_col, end_row, end_col
        If there is no selection, returns selected cell's start_row=end_row, start_col=end_col
        """
        if not len(self.GetSelectionBlockTopLeft()):
            selected_columns = self.GetSelectedCols()
            selected_rows = self.GetSelectedRows()
            if selected_columns:
                start_col = selected_columns[0]
                end_col = selected_columns[-1]
                start_row = 0
                end_row = self.GetNumberRows() - 1
            elif selected_rows:
                start_row = selected_rows[0]
                end_row = selected_rows[-1]
                start_col = 0
                end_col = self.GetNumberCols() - 1
            else:
                start_row = end_row = self.GetGridCursorRow()
                start_col = end_col = self.GetGridCursorCol()
        elif len(self.GetSelectionBlockTopLeft()) > 1:
            wx.MessageBox("Multiple selections are not supported", "Warning")
            return []
        else:
            start_row, start_col = self.GetSelectionBlockTopLeft()[0]
            end_row, end_col = self.GetSelectionBlockBottomRight()[0]

        return [start_row, start_col, end_row, end_col]

    def get_selected_cells(self):
        # returns a list of selected cells
        selection = self.get_selection()
        if not selection:
            return

        start_row, start_col, end_row, end_col = selection
        for row in range(start_row, end_row + 1):
            for col in range(start_col, end_col + 1):
                yield [row, col]

    def copy(self, event):
        """
        Copies range of selected cells to clipboard.
        """

        selection = self.get_selection()
        if not selection:
            return []
        start_row, start_col, end_row, end_col = selection

        data = u''

        rows = range(start_row, end_row + 1)
        for row in rows:
            columns = range(start_col, end_col + 1)
            for idx, column in enumerate(columns, 1):
                if idx == len(columns):
                    # if we are at the last cell of the row, add new line instead
                    data += self.GetCellValue(row, column) + "\n"
                else:
                    data += self.GetCellValue(row, column) + "\t"

        text_data_object = wx.TextDataObject()
        text_data_object.SetText(data)

        if wx.TheClipboard.Open():
            wx.TheClipboard.SetData(text_data_object)
            wx.TheClipboard.Close()
        else:
            wx.MessageBox("Can't open the clipboard", "Warning")

    def paste(self, event):
        if not wx.TheClipboard.Open():
            wx.MessageBox("Can't open the clipboard", "Warning")
            return False

        clipboard = wx.TextDataObject()
        wx.TheClipboard.GetData(clipboard)
        wx.TheClipboard.Close()
        data = clipboard.GetText()
        if data[-1] == "\n":
            data = data[:-1]

        try:
            cells = self.get_selected_cells()
            cell = next(cells)
        except StopIteration:
            return False

        start_row = end_row = cell[0]
        start_col = end_col = cell[1]
        max_row = self.GetNumberRows()
        max_col = self.GetNumberCols()

        history = []
        out_of_range = False

        for row, line in enumerate(data.split("\n")):
            target_row = start_row + row
            if not (0 <= target_row < max_row):
                out_of_range = True
                break

            if target_row > end_row:
                end_row = target_row

            for col, value in enumerate(line.split("\t")):
                target_col = start_col + col
                if not (0 <= target_col < max_col):
                    out_of_range = True
                    break

                if target_col > end_col:
                    end_col = target_col

                # save previous value of the cell for undo
                history.append([target_row, target_col, {"value": self.GetCellValue(target_row, target_col)}])

                self.SetCellValue(target_row, target_col, value)

        self.SelectBlock(start_row, start_col, end_row, end_col)  # select pasted range
        if out_of_range:
            wx.MessageBox("Pasted data is out of Grid range", "Warning")

        self.add_history({"type": "change", "cells": history})

    def delete(self, event):
        cells = []
        for row, col in self.get_selected_cells():
            attributes = {
                "value": self.GetCellValue(row, col),
                "alignment": self.GetCellAlignment(row, col)
            }
            cells.append((row, col, attributes))
            self.SetCellValue(row, col, "")

        self.add_history({"type": "delete", "cells": cells})

    def cut(self, event):
        self.copy(event)
        self.delete(event)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    class MyFrame(wx.Frame):
        def __init__(self, parent, ID, title, pos=wx.DefaultPosition, size=wx.Size(800, 400), style=wx.DEFAULT_FRAME_STYLE):
            wx.Frame.__init__(self, parent, ID, title, pos, size, style)
            agrid = MyGrid(self)
            agrid.CreateGrid(7, 7)
            for count in range(3):
                for count2 in range(3):
                    agrid.SetCellValue(count, count2, str(count + count2))

    class MyApp(wx.App):
        def OnInit(self):
            frame = MyFrame(None, -1, "A copy and paste grid")
            frame.Show(True)
            self.SetTopWindow(frame)
            return True

    app = MyApp()
    app.MainLoop()
```

Answer (score 2):

Thanks for the great piece of code. I needed a custom grid that allows Excel like pasting (i.e. copying a single row or column to multiple rows or columns). I extended your code to include the additional functionality I needed. Here is my extended version of your posted code.

```
import wx
import wx.grid


class MyFrame(wx.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent, ID, title, pos=wx.DefaultPosition,
                 size=wx.Size(800, 400), style=wx.DEFAULT_FRAME_STYLE):
        wx.Frame.__init__(self, parent, ID, title, pos, size, style)
        agrid = CpGrid(self, -1, wx.WANTS_CHARS)
        agrid.CreateGrid(7, 7)
        for count in range(3):
            for count2 in range(3):
                agrid.SetCellValue(count, count2, str(count + count2))


class CpGrid(wx.grid.Grid):
    """ A Full Copy and Paste enabled grid class which implements Excel
    like copy, paste, and delete functionality.

    Ctrl+c - Copy range of selected cells.
    Ctrl+v - Paste copy selection at point of currently selected cell.
             If paste selection is larger than copy selection,
             copy selection will be replicated to fill paste
             region if it is a modulo number of copy rows and/or
             columns, otherwise just the copy selection will be pasted.
    Ctrl+x - Delete current selection. Deleted selection can be
             restored with Ctrl+z, or pasted with Ctrl+v.
             Delete or backspace key will also perform this action.
    Ctrl+z - Undo the last paste or delete action.

    """

    def __init__(self, parent, id, style):
        wx.grid.Grid.__init__(self, parent, id, wx.DefaultPosition,
                              wx.DefaultSize, style)

        # bind key down events
        wx.EVT_KEY_DOWN(self, self.OnKey)

        # initialize text string for undo (start row, start col, undo string)
        self.data4undo = [0, 0, '']

        # initialize copy rows and columns
        # catches case of initial Ctrl+v before a Ctrl+c
        self.crows = 1
        self.ccols = 1

        # initialize clipboard to empty string
        data = ''

        # Create text data object
        clipboard = wx.TextDataObject()

        # Set data object value
        clipboard.SetText(data)

        # Put the data in the clipboard
        if wx.TheClipboard.Open():
            wx.TheClipboard.SetData(clipboard)
            wx.TheClipboard.Close()
        else:
            wx.MessageBox("Can't open the clipboard", "Error")

    def OnKey(self, event):
        '''Handles all key events.
        '''

        # If Ctrl+c is pressed...
        if event.ControlDown() and event.GetKeyCode() == 67:
            self.copy()

        # If Ctrl+v is pressed...
        if event.ControlDown() and event.GetKeyCode() == 86:
            self.paste('paste')

        # If Ctrl+Z is pressed...
        if event.ControlDown() and event.GetKeyCode() == 90:
            if self.data4undo[2] != '':
                self.paste('undo')

        # If del, backspace or Ctrl+x is pressed...
        if event.GetKeyCode() == 127 or event.GetKeyCode() == 8 \
                or (event.ControlDown() and event.GetKeyCode() == 88):
            # Call delete method
            self.delete()

        # Skip other Key events
        if event.GetKeyCode():
            event.Skip()
            return

    def copy(self):
        '''Copies the current range of select cells to clipboard.
        '''
        # Get number of copy rows and cols
        if self.GetSelectionBlockTopLeft() == []:
            rowstart = self.GetGridCursorRow()
            colstart = self.GetGridCursorCol()
            rowend = rowstart
            colend = colstart
        else:
            rowstart = self.GetSelectionBlockTopLeft()[0][0]
            colstart = self.GetSelectionBlockTopLeft()[0][1]
            rowend = self.GetSelectionBlockBottomRight()[0][0]
            colend = self.GetSelectionBlockBottomRight()[0][1]

        self.crows = rowend - rowstart + 1
        self.ccols = colend - colstart + 1

        # data variable contains text that must be set in the clipboard
        data = ''

        # For each cell in selected range append the cell value
        # in the data variable Tabs '\t' for cols and '\n' for rows
        for r in range(self.crows):
            for c in range(self.ccols):
                data += str(self.GetCellValue(rowstart + r, colstart + c))
                if c < self.ccols - 1:
                    data += '\t'
            data += '\n'

        # Create text data object
        clipboard = wx.TextDataObject()

        # Set data object value
        clipboard.SetText(data)

        # Put the data in the clipboard
        if wx.TheClipboard.Open():
            wx.TheClipboard.SetData(clipboard)
            wx.TheClipboard.Close()
        else:
            wx.MessageBox("Can't open the clipboard", "Error")

    def build_paste_selection(self):
        '''This method creates the paste selection, builds it
        into a clipboard string, and puts it on the clipboard.
        When building the paste selection it fills in replicas
        of the copy selection if: number of rows and/or columns
        in the paste selection is larger than the copy selection,
        and they are multiples of the corresponding copy selection
        rows and/or columns, otherwise just the copy selection
        will be used.
        '''

        # Get number of copy rows and cols
        if self.GetSelectionBlockTopLeft() == []:
            rowstart = self.GetGridCursorRow()
            colstart = self.GetGridCursorCol()
            rowend = rowstart
            colend = colstart
        else:
            rowstart = self.GetSelectionBlockTopLeft()[0][0]
            colstart = self.GetSelectionBlockTopLeft()[0][1]
            rowend = self.GetSelectionBlockBottomRight()[0][0]
            colend = self.GetSelectionBlockBottomRight()[0][1]

        self.prows = rowend - rowstart + 1
        self.pcols = colend - colstart + 1

        # find if paste selection area is a multiple of the copy selection
        rows_mod = not(bool(self.prows % self.crows))
        cols_mod = not(bool(self.pcols % self.ccols))

        # initialize to default case (i.e. paste equals copy)
        row_copies = 1
        col_copies = 1

        # one row multiple column paste selection
        if self.prows == 1 and self.pcols > 1 and cols_mod:
            col_copies = self.pcols / self.ccols  # int division

        # one col multiple row paste selection
        if self.prows > 1 and rows_mod and self.pcols == 1:
            row_copies = self.prows / self.crows  # int division

        # mulitple row and column paste selection
        if self.prows > 1 and rows_mod and self.pcols > 1 and cols_mod:
            row_copies = self.prows / self.crows  # int division
            col_copies = self.pcols / self.ccols  # int division

        clipboard = wx.TextDataObject()
        if wx.TheClipboard.Open():
            wx.TheClipboard.GetData(clipboard)
            wx.TheClipboard.Close()
        else:
            wx.MessageBox("Can't open the clipboard", "Error")

        data = clipboard.GetText()

        # column expansion (fill out additional columns)
        out_values = []
        for row, text in enumerate(data.splitlines()):
            string = text
            for i in range(col_copies - 1):
                string += '\t' + text
            out_values.append(string)

        # row expansion (fill out additional rows)
        out_values *= row_copies

        # build output text string for clipboard
        self.out_data = '\n'.join(out_values)

    def paste(self, mode):
        '''Handles paste and undo operations.
        '''

        # perform paste or undo action
        if mode == 'paste':
            # create the paste string from the copy string
            self.build_paste_selection()

            if self.GetSelectionBlockTopLeft() == []:
                rowstart = self.GetGridCursorRow()
                colstart = self.GetGridCursorCol()
            else:
                rowstart = self.GetSelectionBlockTopLeft()[0][0]
                colstart = self.GetSelectionBlockTopLeft()[0][1]
        elif mode == 'undo':
            self.out_data = self.data4undo[2]
            rowstart = self.data4undo[0]
            colstart = self.data4undo[1]
        else:
            wx.MessageBox("Paste method " + mode + " does not exist", "Error")

        # paste current paste selection and build a clipboard string for undo
        text4undo = ''  # initialize
        for y, r in enumerate(self.out_data.splitlines()):
            # Convert c in a array of text separated by tab
            for x, c in enumerate(r.split('\t')):
                if y + rowstart < self.NumberRows and \
                        x + colstart < self.NumberCols:
                    text4undo += str(self.GetCellValue(rowstart + y,
                                                       colstart + x)) + '\t'
                    self.SetCellValue(rowstart + y, colstart + x, c)

            text4undo = text4undo[:-1] + '\n'

        # save current paste selection for undo
        if mode == 'paste':
            self.data4undo = [rowstart, colstart, text4undo]
        else:
            self.data4undo = [0, 0, '']

    def delete(self):
        '''This method deletes text from selected cells, places a
        copy of the deleted cells on the clipboard for pasting
        (Ctrl+v), and places a copy in the self.data4undo variable
        for undoing (Ctrl+z)
        '''

        # Get number of delete rows and cols
        if self.GetSelectionBlockTopLeft() == []:
            rowstart = self.GetGridCursorRow()
            colstart = self.GetGridCursorCol()
            rowend = rowstart
            colend = colstart
        else:
            rowstart = self.GetSelectionBlockTopLeft()[0][0]
            colstart = self.GetSelectionBlockTopLeft()[0][1]
            rowend = self.GetSelectionBlockBottomRight()[0][0]
            colend = self.GetSelectionBlockBottomRight()[0][1]

        rows = rowend - rowstart + 1
        cols = colend - colstart + 1

        # Save deleted text and clear cells contents
        text4undo = ''
        for r in range(rows):
            for c in range(cols):
                text4undo += \
                    str(self.GetCellValue(rowstart + r, colstart + c)) + '\t'
                self.SetCellValue(rowstart + r, colstart + c, '')

            text4undo = text4undo[:-1] + '\n'

        # Save a copy of deleted text for undo
        self.data4undo = [rowstart, colstart, text4undo]

        # Save a copy of deleted text to clipboard for Ctrl+v
        clipboard = wx.TextDataObject()
        clipboard.SetText(text4undo)
        if wx.TheClipboard.Open():
            wx.TheClipboard.SetData(clipboard)
            wx.TheClipboard.Close()
        else:
            wx.MessageBox("Can't open the clipboard", "Error")


class MyApp(wx.App):
    def OnInit(self):
        frame = MyFrame(None, -1,
                        "A copy and paste grid")
        frame.Show(True)
        self.SetTopWindow(frame)
        return True


def main():
    app = MyApp()
    app.MainLoop()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```